# Compare two large text files with Java

Tags: java

I read two files (a large file and a small file)

The first file contains both capital letters and small letters
But second file contains just capital letters.

Program first extract capital letters from first(large file) file and then compare with second file (that contains just capital letters).

My code works well when the large files are small, But when my file size is about 400MB the program show an internal error `"Java Out of Memory Error"`.

Here is my code:

```
public class SequenceComparator {

private ArrayList<Sequence> bigSequences;
private ArrayList<Sequence> smallSequences;

public SequenceComparator() {
    bigSequences = new ArrayList<Sequence>();
    smallSequences = new ArrayList<Sequence>();
}

private String splitUpperSequences(String bigSeq) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : bigSeq.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public void readBigSequences() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("test_ref_Aviso_bristol_k_31_c_4.fa"));
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String title = s.nextLine();
        if (!title.startsWith(">")) {
            continue;
        }
        String seq = s.nextLine();
        Sequence sequence = new Sequence(title, splitUpperSequences(seq).trim());
        bigSequences.add(sequence);
    }
    s.close();

}

public void readSmallSequences() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("SNP12K.fasta"));
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String title = s.nextLine().trim();
        if (!title.startsWith(">")) {
            continue;
        }
        String seq = s.nextLine().trim();
        Sequence sequence = new Sequence(title, seq);
        smallSequences.add(sequence);
    }
    s.close();

}

public void printSeqArray(ArrayList<Sequence> seqArray) {
    for (Sequence sequence : seqArray) {
        System.out.println(sequence);
    }
}

private void reportNotFoundSeqs(ArrayList<Sequence> notFoundSeqs) {
    System.out.println("Sequence that is not similar with big file:\n\n");
    printSeqArray(notFoundSeqs);
}

public void comparison() {
    int bigLength = bigSequences.size();
    int smallLength = smallSequences.size();
    System.out.println("Sequences Length of big file is " + bigLength);
    System.out.println("Sequences Length of small file is " + smallLength);
    System.out.println("\n");
    if (bigLength > smallLength) {
        System.out.println("big file has " + (bigLength - smallLength) + " sequence more than smal file");
    } else {
        System.out.println("small file has " + (smallLength - bigLength) + " sequence more than big file");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    int s = 0;
    ArrayList<Sequence> notFoundSeqs = new ArrayList<Sequence>();
    for (Sequence smalSeq : smallSequences) {
        if (bigSequences.contains(smalSeq)) {
            s++;
        } else {
            notFoundSeqs.add(smalSeq);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Tow files are similar in " + s + " point");
    System.out.println("\n");
    reportNotFoundSeqs(notFoundSeqs);

}

public ArrayList<Sequence> getBigSequences() {
    return bigSequences;
}

public ArrayList<Sequence> getSmallSequences() {
    return smallSequences;
}

static public void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException { 
    SequenceComparator sc = new SequenceComparator();

System.out.println("Reading files..."); 
long befor = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
sc.readBigSequences();
System.out.println("\nBig file upper sequences:\n");
sc.printSeqArray(sc.getBigSequences());

sc.readSmallSequences();

sc.comparison(); 
long afer = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
System.out.println("Time: "+((afer-befor)/1000)+" Seconds"); }

class Sequence {

    private String title;
    private String seq;

    public Sequence(String title, String seq) {
        this.seq = seq;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Sequence() {
    }

    public String getSeq() {
        return seq;
    }

    public void setSeq(String seq) {
        this.seq = seq;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nTitle: " + title + "\n" + "Sequence: " + seq + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Sequence other = (Sequence) obj;
        return seq.equals(other.seq);
    }

}
}
```

What can i do?

Comment: don't put everything in memory and do the reading line by line?

Comment: Give the JVM more memory with `-Xmx512M`. Unless your file is > 512 MB...

Comment: @DavidEhrmann where should i use this statement?

Comment: @user3808021 When you run the `java` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading the whole file content into your memory. That's why you got the Out of Memory Error. Try instead to create a temp files of equal format and the compare both files line by line. Delete the temp file at the end.

Example:

```
private File prepareFile(String rawFirstFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File tempFile = new File("rawFirstFile_temp.dat");

    try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(new File(rawFirstFile).toPath());
        BufferedWriter wr = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE)){

        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //
            // change the raw line, save filtered data as new line in your temp file
            // what ever you want. example:
            //      title1,seq1
            //      title2,seq2
            //      ...
            //
            wr.write(changeLine(line));
            wr.newLine();
        }
        return tempFile;
    }
}

public void compareFiles(String firstFile, String seconFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    File tempFirstFile  = prepareFile(firstFile);
    File secondFile     = new File(seconFile); // maybe need to prepare too

    try(BufferedReader  br1 = Files.newBufferedReader(tempFirstFile.toPath());
        BufferedReader  br2 = Files.newBufferedReader(secondFile.toPath())){

        String line1File = null;
        String line2File = null;

        // line by line
        while ((line1File = br1.readLine()) != null && (line2File = br2.readLine()) != null ) {
            //
            // compare them
            //
        }
    } finally {
        if(tempFirstFile != null){
            //tempFirstFile.deleteOnExit(); 
            Files.delete(tempFirstFile.toPath()); // has no effect if deleteOnExit was called!
        }
    }

}

private String changeLine(String rawLine) {
    //TODO
    return rawLine;
}
```

edit: changed try-catch to try-with statement to get the answer more smarter

Answer (score 0):

You should perform a byte by byte comparison, not line by line as mentioned by dit.  If the source of the file is unknown, using readLine() is prone to attack.